# Exchange store.exe memory spiking bewteen midnight and 6AM

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, memory, exchange-2007, memory-usage

I have a windows server 2003 R2 64bits SP2 with Exchange Server 2007 installed.

The server has 12GB of ram and during the night, always between 12PM and 6AM, the memory usage spikes to 100% with store.exe using most of it.

Now I know that Exchange Server will use as much memory as possible and release it whenever another process needs it. But it's not what's happening here, during the day the memory usage is around 50%.

I've checked, and there are no backups running between 12PM and 6AM. Our Backups run between 6AM and 9AM, and at 9PM at night.

From the statistics I have, this behaviour has been going for a while now (at least 3 months) but it's only for the past week that we've received alerts.

So my question is: is there something that exchange server does during that time that's so memory hungry?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could be the maintenance of the exchange databases?

Comment: Are you seeing anything in your Logs during that time?  My guess, as others mention, is that Database Maintenance is occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I know that Exchange Server will use as much memory as possible
>   and release it whenever another process needs it

I don't believe that to be the case and I've never seen documentation or anecdotal evidence to suggest such behavior.

Database maintenance occurs by default between 1AM and 5AM. That would be my guess as to what's causing the spike.

See here for a list of maintenance tasks that occur - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123760(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: I got the information from there: http://blogs.technet.com/b/maliks/archive/2012/04/25/exchange-2010-store-exe-service-takes-high-memory-utilization.aspx (and other sources, but this is the main one)

Comment: Thanks a lot joeqwerty, it is the database maintenance. For those interseted, here's the Microsoft technet overview of the Exchange Store maintenance: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996226(v=exchg.65).aspx

Comment: Glad to help...